# Split subdomains to separate DNS servers

Tags: domain-name-system

Is it possible to have subdomains split on to two DNS servers?

```
DNS server 1: mydomain.com A x.x.x.x
DNS server 1: www.mydomain.com CNAME mydomain.com

DNS server 2: xxx.mydomain.com A x.x.x.y
```

I need this because only one subdomain must be used with geo dns service and I want to leave rest of configuration on current DNS servers.

Comment: You need to delegation NS records for that subdomain to the other nameserver.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create an NS record for xxx.example.com and point it to a secondary name server.

```
; Normal entries for the main domain go here
@     A       192.0.2.80
www   CNAME   mydomain.com.

; Split of a subdomain to a second DNS server
xxx   NS      ns2.example.com.
ns2   A       203.0.113.53
```

This secondary name server can then provide the A record for its apex: “xxx.example.com”.